# Do something after checking if 2 elements in one list are the same

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I wanted to know, how to check whether or not 2 elements in one list are the same. The list is going to be an user input. We loop through the list to print out the index positions of each word inputted. If we come across the same word again in the same input, when we print out the, first user-inputted sentence, as indexes of the actual words (no punctuation), I want my program to display the first index of the same word.

For eg:-

USERINPUT - I like to code because i like it and i like it a lot

There are 14 words. Only 9 are different. So the final output of my program should print their index positions - (+1) - Since python starts indexing from 0 onwards. The final result of the program should be:-

1 2 3 4 5 1 2 6 7 1 2 6 8 9

Comment: SO is not just for you. It is for everyone. You can not just change the content like this. If you do not want to put your question on SO, feel free to delete it. But if it is there, it should be with proper content. Else, next time I'll have to flag the question

Comment: @StreetSoldier please note that all content you post on SE network is [perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140803/260312). You can [send a disassociation request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291837/2301450), if you want.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri To make everyone happy, I have only deleted a part of the question which does not contribute to it at all, but involved some code that i have created, for some copyright issues. I hope this helps everyone and the problem should now be resolved as the full original question is here with no edits at all

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `index()` list method:

```
firstsentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
firstsentence = firstsentence.lower()
words = firstsentence.split(' ')

s = ""

for word in words:
    s += str(words.index(word)+1) + " "

print(s)
```

Comment: Ah but mine indexed from 1!

Comment: Yeah sure just change the last line to `my_indexes = ' '.join(str(unique_list.index(word)+1) for word in my_word_list)`

Comment: No problem - sure thing

Comment: @StreetSoldier: SO is for all and we are here to help everyone. Rest is up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like:

```
my_string = "I like to code because i like it and i like it a lot"

# Convert string to lower-case alphabets
my_string = my_string.lower()

# list of words in sentence
my_word_list = my_string.split()

# List to maintain unique words with index
unique_list = []
for word in my_word_list:
    if word not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(word)

#                Find index of word in list + 1  v
my_indexes = ' '.join(str(unique_list.index(word)+1) for word in my_word_list)
```

Final value hold by `my_indexes` will be:

```
'1 2 3 4 5 1 2 6 7 1 2 6 8 9'
```

Comment: @StreetSoldier: In the *list comprehension* expression, i.e. the last line of the code, you need to do :`unique_list.index(word)+1`. BTW I updated my answer. Check edit

Comment: Last line to `my_indexes = ' '.join(str(unique_list.index(word)+1) for word in my_word_list)` for correct indexing

Comment: #SOReadyToHelp ;)